# Agrupamento de linhas incorreto

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli

Olá alguém consegue me ajudar, eu estou tentando trazer um relatório de empresa e atividade feitos em 12 meses, uma empresa e uma atividade foi feita durante 12 meses e quero saber de cada atividade se ela foi feita em janeiro, fevereiro,  março etc, o problema é que não esta agrupando por empresa corretamente o mês a mês.

Meu código.

```
SELECT   
empresas,
tipo_atividade,
CASE WHEN MONTH(dt_fim) = '1'   THEN IFNULL('OK','PENDENTE')  ELSE  'PENDENTE' END AS MES_1,
CASE WHEN MONTH(dt_fim) = '2'   THEN IFNULL('OK','PENDENTE')  ELSE  'PENDENTE' END AS MES_2,
CASE WHEN MONTH(dt_fim) = '3'   THEN IFNULL('OK','PENDENTE')  ELSE  'PENDENTE' END AS MES_3,
CASE WHEN MONTH(dt_fim) = '4'   THEN IFNULL('OK','PENDENTE')  ELSE  'PENDENTE' END AS MES_4,
CASE WHEN MONTH(dt_fim) = '5'   THEN IFNULL('OK','PENDENTE')  ELSE  'PENDENTE' END AS MES_5,
CASE WHEN MONTH(dt_fim) = '6'   THEN IFNULL('OK','PENDENTE')  ELSE  'PENDENTE' END AS MES_6,
CASE WHEN MONTH(dt_fim) = '7'   THEN IFNULL('OK','PENDENTE')  ELSE  'PENDENTE' END AS MES_7,
CASE WHEN MONTH(dt_fim) = '8'   THEN IFNULL('OK','PENDENTE')  ELSE  'PENDENTE' END AS MES_8,
CASE WHEN MONTH(dt_fim) = '9'   THEN IFNULL('OK','PENDENTE')  ELSE  'PENDENTE' END AS MES_9,
CASE WHEN MONTH(dt_fim) = '10'   THEN IFNULL('OK','PENDENTE')  ELSE  'PENDENTE' END AS MES_10,
CASE WHEN MONTH(dt_fim) = '11'   THEN IFNULL('OK','PENDENTE')  ELSE  'PENDENTE' END AS MES_11,
CASE WHEN MONTH(dt_fim) = '12'   THEN IFNULL('OK','PENDENTE')  ELSE  'PENDENTE' END AS MES_12

FROM tbl_atividades
WHERE 
YEAR(dt_fim) = '2019' AND 
(STATUS = 'CONCLUIDO' OR STATUS = 'CONCLUIDO_VENCIDO')
ORDER BY empresas, tipo_atividade;
```

O resultado é o seguinte
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando uso a clausula GROUP BY EMPRESAS o resultado fica errado.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Também tentei

```
GROUP BY EMPRESAS
GROUP BY EMPRESAS, TIPO_ATIVIDADE
GROUP BY TIPO_ATIVIDADE
```

Todos deram errado , o que eu preciso fazer para exibir corretamente por empresa e atividade no mes a mes em uma única linha.

Comment: Você tem que especificar uma função de agregação.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma das maneiras de resolver isso seria contando quantos registros tem `dt_fim` no mês correspondente e atendem aos outros critérios do `WHERE`, depois de chegar nesse valor, você verifica se existe algum registro naquele mês, se existir, preenche com `OK`, caso contrário `PENDENTE`, algo do tipo:

```
SELECT   
  empresas,
  tipo_atividade,
  CASE WHEN (SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(dt_fim) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) > 0 THEN 'OK' ELSE 'PENDENTE' END AS MES_1,
  CASE WHEN (SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(dt_fim) = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) > 0 THEN 'OK' ELSE 'PENDENTE' END AS MES_2,
  CASE WHEN (SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(dt_fim) = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) > 0 THEN 'OK' ELSE 'PENDENTE' END AS MES_3,
  CASE WHEN (SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(dt_fim) = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) > 0 THEN 'OK' ELSE 'PENDENTE' END AS MES_4,
  CASE WHEN (SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(dt_fim) = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) > 0 THEN 'OK' ELSE 'PENDENTE' END AS MES_5,
  CASE WHEN (SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(dt_fim) = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) > 0 THEN 'OK' ELSE 'PENDENTE' END AS MES_6,
  CASE WHEN (SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(dt_fim) = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) > 0 THEN 'OK' ELSE 'PENDENTE' END AS MES_7,
  CASE WHEN (SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(dt_fim) = 8 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) > 0 THEN 'OK' ELSE 'PENDENTE' END AS MES_8,
  CASE WHEN (SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(dt_fim) = 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) > 0 THEN 'OK' ELSE 'PENDENTE' END AS MES_9,
  CASE WHEN (SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(dt_fim) = 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) > 0 THEN 'OK' ELSE 'PENDENTE' END AS MES_10,
  CASE WHEN (SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(dt_fim) = 11 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) > 0 THEN 'OK' ELSE 'PENDENTE' END AS MES_11,
  CASE WHEN (SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(dt_fim) = 12 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) > 0 THEN 'OK' ELSE 'PENDENTE' END AS MES_12
FROM 
  tbl_atividades
WHERE 
  YEAR(dt_fim) = '2019' AND (STATUS = 'CONCLUIDO' OR STATUS = 'CONCLUIDO_VENCIDO')
GROUP BY 
  empresas, tipo_atividade;
```

O `SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(dt_fim) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)` faz a contagem que eu informei.